# Add marker listener to all markers in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-bigquery

I have made a website with a map using the Google Maps Javascript API. Im using PHP to call $rows from a Google BigQuery database. I want to add a listener to all markers on the map. Currently any marker clicked jumps to the final marker as if its looping through all remaining markers to the final marker.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) { 

            ?>
            var contentString = "<h1><?php echo str_replace('"', "'", $row['f'][2]['v']); ?></h1>";
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
                });

            var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['f'][0]['v']; ?> , <?php echo $row['f'][1]['v']; ?>);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: geolocate,
                icon: '/img/Toilet.png',
                title: "<?php echo str_replace('"', "'", $row['f'][2]['v']); ?>"                        //String Replace
                });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
```

I imaging that marker.addListener needs a pointer to the array index but i cant work it out, What do I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: Ive tried this fix but I'm using a foreach loop, the indexing for a while loop doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IIFE pattern. Please have a look at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

In this case your code will be something like:

```
<?php
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
?>
     (function() {
         var contentString = "<h1><?php echo str_replace('"', "'", $row['f'][2]['v']); ?></h1>";
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
             content: contentString
         });

         var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['f'][0]['v']; ?> , <?php echo $row['f'][1]['v']; ?>);

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: geolocate,
             icon: '/img/Toilet.png',
             title: "<?php echo str_replace('"', "'", $row['f'][2]['v']); ?>"                        //String Replace
            });

         marker.addListener('click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
         });
    })();
<?php 
}
?>
```